# If we change the direction of the connections in a step-down transformer, will it become a step-up transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, terminology, inductance, electrical-engineering

If we change the direction of the connections in a step-down transformer, will it become a step-up transformer?

Comment: If you intend to actually try this, *please* be careful. Don't exceed the transformer's power or current ratings. And definitely do *not* feed mains voltage into the output side of a step-down transformer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. The resulting step-up ratio will be the inverse of the step-down ratio.

Comment: It's very important to heed PM 2Ring's warning: "And definitely do not feed mains voltage into the output side of a step-down transformer." The secondary of a step-down transformer (for example one that gives you 6 V when 240 V ac is applied across the primary) will have only a few turns and therefore too low a self-inductance to limit the current to a safe value.

Answer (score 0):

Transformers are pretty much bi-directional devices in regard to the direction of the energy transfer and this property is routinelu used in power distribution systems.

E.g a power pole transformer can feed a 230/400V (or 120/240V in the US) domestic grid from a 10kV power line at night and pretty much feed back the extra power generated from the photovoltaics at the same area during the day. This happens without any changes at the transformer itself, it just hangs from the pole and hums.

On the other hand, transformers have their limitations that may limit their reversibility. E.g if you have 240/120V transformer  and you try to feed it 240V on its 120 side, chances are that something will break or burn soon, but for a brief while you will have 480V at the other side.